# Use ssmtp to a gmail account from a server

Tags: email, gmail, ssmtp

I have an Ubuntu server which I'd like to use for sending emails through a gmail account. I use sSMTP, a simple unix email sending client.

I double checked my configuration as per http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1691878

It appea*rs google is just blocking my (server) IP address until I web login from the same host to confirm some security check. 
But I'm on a server with no practical way of using the web interface.

Anybody know a way out? Should I quit using google?

Comment: There are few text mode browsers, and you can also simulate browser with wget or curl (save the cookies!)

Comment: don't know if it relevant here, but when I was set up for EXIM to use gmail as a smart host, gmail was real choosey about the envelope headers.  for example, the from had to be from a gmail address, maybe even the particular address you are smtping from.  I did a simple rewrire of the FROM header and it started to work.  Can you enable logging verbosely on ssmtp?